# A bar that takes date input by range and also let us write tags in it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a responsive time sheet. i want to take input by date ranges so that if user selects date 1-july on one end and 10 july on other end, i must get 2 dates and it must be able to take input about the work. 
for example i selected 1-july on one end and 10 july on other end. and in that span, i want to put a tag that this task was done in this time span.
like this: 
http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/range.html
instead of price range, i want date ranges and i must be able to define tags inside it. 
any ideas of how to do this in html5, jquery or javasript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your answer...enjoy!

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#dateSliderQuickStart

Comment: i also want to define tags inside it.

Comment: I can think of tons of ways to implement that, why not hack something up using this jQRangeSlider.....??? At least it will get you further than without using it